# Is ASP.NET MVC just installed on Visual Studio or is installed on IIS too?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

I'm going to deploy an ASP.NET MVC project on IIS (6.0 & 7.5) but don't now is it necessary to install anything on IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [good tutorial for this on the asp.net](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-08-cs.aspx) site.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can deploy everything in the web app.

Just make sure the references for mvc point to you bin folder